# "Could not resolve matching constructor" error when passing in constructor-arg for child class

Tags: java, spring, inheritance, constructor

I have the following classes:

```
public abstract class ParentClass
{
    public ParentClass()
    {
        throw new RuntimeException("An ID must be specified.");
    }

    public ParentClass(String id)
    {
        this(id, DEFUALT_ARG_VALUE);
    }

    public ParentClass(String id, int anotherArg)
    {
        this.id = id;
        //stuff with anotherArg
    }

    public abstract void doInstanceStuff();
}

public class ChildClass extends ParentClass
{
    @Override
    public void doInstanceStuff()
    {
        //....
    }
}
```

In my application context I have this:

```
<bean id="myChildInstance" class="com.foo.bar.ChildClass " scope="singleton">
    <constructor-arg value="myId" />
</bean>
```

The problem is that when the server starts up I get the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ivpluginHealthCheckTest' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml]: Could not resolve matching constructor (hint: specify index/type/name arguments for simple parameters to avoid type ambiguities)
```

Seeing the error, I tried adding the different attributes, but with no luck. I ended up with something like this:

```
<bean id="myChildInstance" class="com.foo.bar.ChildClass " scope="singleton">
    <constructor-arg value="myId" index="0" type="java.lang.String" name="id" />
</bean>
```

And I still get the same error.

I tried adding the same constructors to my child class, and just call `super()` with the appropriate arguments for each one, and that seems to fix it. However, I don't want to have to add the same constructors in all my child instances and have to maintain those with the parent class.

Is there some reason Spring has trouble calling an inherited constructor to instantiate the class? Is there something I can do to make this work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> calling an inherited constructor to instantiate the class?

Constructors are never inherited, and it doesn't really make sense. A constructor just initializes the state in that particular class. You can't expect a constructor of `Parent` to initialize the state of `Child` class. That's the job of constructor in `Child` class only.

So, no you can't do what you are trying to do. And that's not the issue with Spring. That's pretty much fundamental.

Comment: It's not as obvious as you make it sound.   We assume that all methods are inherited via extending from a class and the constructor definition is technically a method, so I could see how one would think it is possible to inherit constructor methods.

Comment: @MohammadS. Hmm. Yeah you're right. Removed that part of my answer.

Comment: What you're saying makes sense. At one point, I left only the default constructor in the parent class, with nothing in the child class, and it did throw the Exception. I guess that's because the default constructor is implied with an implied super call (unless I'm misunderstanding that too). That just made me think the other ones were being inherited too.

Comment: @dnc253 Yes, the default constructor will always be added by the compiler, if you don't provide any constructor.

Comment: @dnc253 You are right. The implicit default constructor in your child class implictly calls `super()`. Hence the default constructor of the super class is called.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: Constructors are not inherited in Java.

From the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8):

```
Constructor declarations are not members. They are never inherited and therefore are not subject to hiding or overriding.
```

This means you have to declare the constructors needed for each subclass and call the corresponding super constructor. Even if it has the same signature it doesn't count as overriding.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not provide a constructor in your child class,the compiler inserts a no-arg constructor and adds the first line as call to super no-arg constructor
So your code becomes :-

```
public class ChildClass extends ParentClass {

        public ChildClass() {
            super();
        }
    }
```

Obviously, u have thrown a null pointer exception  which may be causing the problem.I suggest you to add a constructor and make a call to super constrcutor which takes String argument:-

```
public class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
        public ChildClass(String id) {
            super(id);
        }

        @Override
        public void doInstanceStuff() {
            // ....
        }
    }
```

This should solve all your problems...

Note:- If you add a argument constructor,the compiler doesn't not add a default constructor for you.

Now your beans will initialize properly as it will call the string argument constructor. Currently the compiler is providing a default no-arg constrcutor for you which in turn is calling your no arg parent class constructor and is throwing a null pointer exception..