# Instantiate base class when child does not implement all constructors

Tags: java, spring, inversion-of-control

Consider a simple bean:

```
@Component
@Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public class A {
    public A(Integer a){}
    public A(String a){}
}
```

Having an instance of [`BeanFactory`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory.html) I can create `A` instances with:

```
beanFactory.getBean(A.class, 1); //  using A(Integer)
beanFactory.getBean(A.class, "1"); //  using A(String)
```

Now, I want to have a subclass of `A` that uses one of the two constructors provided. My class hierarchy now becomes:

```
@Component
@Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
@Primary
public class A {
    public A(Integer a) {}
    public A(String a) {}
}

@Component
@Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public class A1 extends A {
    public A1() { super(1); }
}
```

I would expect these to work now:

```
beanFactory.getBean(A.class, 1); // using A(Integer)
beanFactory.getBean(A.class, "1"); // using A(String)
beanFactory.getBean(A1.class); // using the A1()
```

However, first two calls fail with

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'A1' defined in file [...]: Could not resolve matching constructor 
(hint: specify index/type/name arguments for simple parameters to avoid type ambiguities)
```

Please note that I'm not trying to create subclass with some argument like author of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21583399/could-not-resolve-matching-constructor-error-when-passing-in-constructor-arg-f).

Also note that if I define (useless) `A1(Integer)` and `A1(String)` constructors, Spring does not complain anymore.

Using Spring 4.2.2.RELEASE.

**Why bean factory can not create base class instances with its constructors when I define some child?**

Please find an unit test reproducing it [in Github repo](https://github.com/fracz/stackoverflow-problems/blob/spring-ioc-instantiation-problem/src/test/java/com/example/ioctest/IocIntegrationTest.java).

Comment: You missed to provide the Spring version used.

Comment: Thank you - I have added this info to the question. It's 4.2.2.RELEASE.

Comment: It would be good also to know the dependencies involved. I'm trying to execute your test case and seems to depend on more than one spring module..

Comment: Check the minimal example in [Github repo](https://github.com/fracz/spring-ioc-instantiation-problem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reason for this behavior is this : **Spring don't use constructor args to determine the appropriate bean type to instanciate**. (or, in other words: it only use constructor args to resolve the correct constructor to use)

Let's consider only this line `beanFactory.getBean(A.class, 1);`

The bean resolution is the following :

1. determine all beans with the requested type. In your case : there are 2 possible beans : A or A1 (both are of type A)
2. create one instance of every possible type found at step 1 **and to do it use the most appropriate constructor according given args**. In your case instantiate one A and one A1 using a constructor with an Integer. (side note: we are talking about *prototype beans* here. For *singleton beans* : a new instance is created if and only if it don't already exists)
3. look for a @Primary in all instantiated bean at step 2 (if found return it)
4. look for bean with highest priority in all instantiated bean at step 2 (if found return it)
5. throw a "no unique bean exception"

In your case : the algorithm fail at step 2 when trying to instantiate a bean of type A1 with one Integer argument.

When you define `A1(String)` and `A1(Integer)` : the algorithm don't fail at step 2 and so goes to step 3 and resolve the type because of the @Primary on class A.

[Source code is here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-beans/4.2.0.RELEASE/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/DefaultListableBeanFactory.java#DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean%28java.lang.Class%2Cjava.lang.Object%5B%5D%29). Take a close look at line 353 --> 366 for the algorithm described here.

---

I can only guess the reason for such behavior, but it maybe because you can specify default values for constructor args and therefore: constructor args (passed to `getBean(Class, args...)` ) aren't a valid clue to disambiguate bean type.

Comment: So for class hierarchy of 100 classes it would create 100 instances just to pick one at the end? So weird. Anyway, thank you for an explanation!

Comment: For prototype bean : yes (and indeed, this is not very efficient). For singleton beans : there is only instance created and this is of course this instance that is reused to evaluate if the bean is appropriate for autowiring. (I edit my post to note this)