# spring data elasticsearch bean creation

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, spring-data

I have a problem with spring data elasticsearch bean creation. The elastic search repository bean is not created. And i don't see what could be the problem. Here is mo code:

The config class:

```
    package example.test.mongo.config;

    import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
    import org.elasticsearch.client.Client;
    import org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient;
    import org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Settings;
    import org.elasticsearch.common.transport.InetSocketTransportAddress;
    import org.elasticsearch.transport.client.PreBuiltTransportClient;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableAspectJAutoProxy;
    import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchTemplate;
    import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.config.EnableElasticsearchRepositories;
    import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
    import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.config.EnableMongoRepositories;

    import java.net.InetAddress;
    import java.net.UnknownHostException;


    @Configuration
    @EnableMongoRepositories({"example.test.mongo.app.repo.mongo"})
    @EnableElasticsearchRepositories({"example.test.mongo.app.repo.elasticsearch"})
    @EnableAspectJAutoProxy
    @ComponentScan(basePackages = {"example.test.mongo.app"})
    public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws Exception {
        return new MongoTemplate(new MongoClient("127.0.0.1:27017"), "jobvacancy");
    }

    @Bean
    public Client client() throws UnknownHostException {
        TransportClient client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(Settings.EMPTY)
                .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 9200));
        return client;
    }

    @Bean
    public ElasticsearchTemplate elasticsearchTemplate() throws UnknownHostException {
        return new ElasticsearchTemplate(client());
    }
}
```

The mongodb and elastisearch repository classes are in separate packages.
Here is the elastic search repository class:

```
import eures.reg2018.poc.mongo.app.domain.blob.JobVacancyWithBlob;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.ElasticsearchRepository;



public interface ElasticSearchTestRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<Article, String> {
Page<Article> findByReference(String Reference, Pageable pageable);
}
```

And the exception is:

```
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'elasticSearchTestRepository': Could not resolve matching constructor (hint: specify index/type/name arguments for simple parameters to avoid type ambiguities)
at     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:240)
at     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1193)
at     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1095)
at     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getSingletonFactoryBeanForTypeCheck(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:923)
at     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:804)
at     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isTypeMatch(AbstractBeanFactory.java:558)
at     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:432)
at     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:403)
at     org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beanNamesForTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:220)
at     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1260)
at     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1101)
at     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
at     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835)
at     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
... 14 more
```

Anybody have any ideas why is happening this exception?

Comment: r u specifying index and type in document  ? like - @Document(indexName = "", type = "") , here is link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21583399/could-not-resolve-matching-constructor-error-when-passing-in-constructor-arg-f/21583446  for this exception .

Comment: @Document(indexName = "jobvacancy", type = "article") i only want to see if that repo is created....

Comment: i even tried with a simplified project, using only elastic search... because in this project i used mongodb spring data too (the mongodb worked). But i created a separate maven project with only elastic search and still the same exception.. can you provide a small example of a maven project based on annotations that works? it seems to be the elastic search spring data dependency ... but i am not sure...

Comment: Here is one good link for simple project in spring data elastic search , download and try :-https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/tree/master/spring-data-elasticsearch

Comment: that tutorial doesn't work .. when i execute the tests the following exception occurs: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.elasticsearch.client.Client]: Factory method 'client' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Plugin [aggs-matrix-stats] must be at least a jvm or site plugin